# Batch File - Getting Volume Labels in a For Loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to set up a batch file that will iterate through the local drives on a PC and get the Volume Name of each drive into an Environment Variable that I can then use for further processing.

Here's what I've got so far, but it doesn't return the correct value for the volume label into the VLABEL1 variable inside the For loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%D in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value') do (
    echo Processing Drive %%D
    call :GetLabel %%D VLABEL1
    echo The Label of Volume %%D is !VLABEL1!
    echo.
)
endlocal 
goto :EOF

:GetLabel
setlocal
for /f "tokens=5*" %%A in ('vol "%~1"^|find "Volume in drive "') do (
    set VOLLABEL=%%B
)
set %2=%VOLLABEL%
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

Needles to say I've tried various combinations & permutations, but without success, so I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this from command line and you will see the reason

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value') do echo .[%a].
```

There is an aditional carriage return at the end of each of the lines.

So, it is necessary to eliminate it before calling your subroutine.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in (
    'wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value'
) do for %%D in (%%A) do (
    ....
)
...
```

The aditional `for` loop removes the CR so now you have the correct value in the variable to call your subroutine.

Now, inside your subroutine,

```
set %2=%VOLLABEL%
endlocal
```

The `endlocal` cancels the assignment of the upper line. It is its mission, cancel changes made in the environment since the previous setlocal. So, it is necessary to both, change the variable and cancel the non required changes. To do so, the fact that the parser works on lines can be used. So the code should be written as

```
endlocal & set "%2=%VOLLABEL%"
```

The full line is readed, at parse time all the value reads are replaced with values and then the line is executed. So, when the second command in the line (the `set`)  is executed, there is no access to the `%VOLLABEL%` variable. This read has been replaced with the value of the variable before the `endlocal` were executed.

Comment: TVM for a very helpful explanation, & sorry it took me so long to acknowledge your reply.